# How to customize better exposed filter template?

Tags: 8, theming, views

I'm creating a Drupal site with articles gathered around themes. I created a vocabulary named Theme, to which I added a field picture.

I created a view (named articles) in which I show my articles as a page and added an exposed filter on the theme. I then added Better Exposed Filter module to remove the apply button and apply the filter on selection.

My issue is that I would like to customize the filter to present it as the theme label and the theme picture. I found the template named bef-links.html.twig but was unabled to override it (I tried bef-links--articles.html.twig).

My questions are how can I override the bef template and how can I access my theme picture to customize my filter (is it necessary to do a preprocess to retrieve it ?) ?